# DBeaver will not display certain schemas correctly in the Database Navigator

Tags: db2, db2-400, dbeaver

I'm using DBeaver 5.2.5.201811181655 with IBM DB2/400 v7r3.

I'm trying to see a schema called `WRKCERTO`, but Database Navigator will not show it. The schema is there and I have rights to it, and I'm able to run SQL scripts with its objects, such as `SELECT * FROM WRKCERTO.DAILYT` and it works.

To make matters stranger, when `WRKCERTO` is the only schema in the filters, the contents of a schema which I cannot identify are shown under the *connection* as if the *connection* is their parent. It doesn't show any schema as a node in the tree between the connection & Tables, Views, etc. The tables are familiar, but I cannot determine their exact schema, and as such also cannot query any of them because DBeaver doesn't know what schema to use.

The behavior of the Projects window is the same.

If I connect with SquirrelSQL 3.8.1 everything looks ok. I can see `WRKCERTO` along with all my other schemas as if nothing is different.

The screenshot below shows the issue. The schema I use most is `F_CERTOB`, which is visible under the connection ASP7, which currently has two schema filters: `F_CERTOB` and `WRKCERTO`. But as shown, `WRKCERTO`...isn't.

The connection `TEST` is an exact copy of `ASP7`, but its only filter is `WRKCERTO`. And as mentioned above, the items under the connection name cannot be identified.

I've gone through the DBeaver settings, but I cannot find any way to change this behavior. AND...this is the first time I've tried to use `WRKCERTO`. I tried to access it for the first time only a couple days ago, so it seems unlikely there are bad bits of information about it floating around in my system, or in DBeaver.

What information can I provide to help diagnose this issue...?

[image]

Comment: Which driver, and driver-version are you using for the connection in dbeaver?
For that driver, which driver properties have you configured?
Is WRKCERTO a synonym or alias?
How do the entries in QSYS2.SCHEMATA differ between the schemas?

Comment: Driver: DB2 iSeries/AS 400. Version/path: \.dbeaver-drivers\maven\maven-central\net.sf.jt400\jt400-9.7.jar. Driver properties: all default. Connection properties: only 'metadata source'=0. SCHEMATA shows the only difference is the owners, but they are ones I do (or should) have rights to. SYSSCHEMAS is similar, but also shows a different IASP_NUMBER. How do I determine if WRKCERTO is a synonym or alias..? It would have to be something that I could check through DBeaver or SQL. This is a cloud-hosted system for which we're denied the use of iNavigator.

Comment: Use QSYS2.SYSTABLES to see table details (table type etc) and compare working schema.table with unseen schema.table.   Which driver is Squirell-SQL using?

Answer (score 2):

Please check below url.Similar issue mentioned with some solution.

You may also want to try this and let me know if it works or not.

https://dbeaver.io/forum/viewtopic.php?f=2&t=911

Comment: Thank you, but unfortunately I do not have direct access to the server to do such work. The server is owned by the publishers of the bookkeeping system that our company subscribes to, and the SQL connection that I have access to is offered "as is" and there is no support. So I muddle through these kinds of idiosyncrasies.  As for the schemas that do not display, I am able to see them with IBM Data Studio, which I keep on hand for comparison when these types of problems arise, but I don't use it for development because I very much prefer DBeaver.

Comment: yeah. I also feel DBeaver is a good tool and I never faced this kind of issue. But schema rebind is one of the option to use when such issue occur.

Comment: if i didn't have the responsibility of caring for my aging parents, i would try to apply at this company and move there if i got the job, i have years of experience running their bookkeeping system